# Neo4j: Load Balancing using Bolt driver in HA mode

Tags: neo4j

We are going to use Bolt driver, our cluster is using HA mode. How bolt supports load balancing in HA mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its own Bolt won't load balance for you. While a causal cluster can use bolt+routing, an HA cluster must use an external load balancer.

Here's the section of the docs on [using HAProxy for load balancing](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/high-availability/haproxy/).

Comment: Thanks InverseFalcon. At present we are using HTTP end points and LB is already configured. But we are also willing to use bolt, so need to know how  load balance can be done using bolt.